# Changing cell height scrolls it off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to expand a cell, by implementing different heights in `heightForRow` method. Everything works mostly ok, but when I'm expanding cell it somehow scrolls off screen. Here is what I mean (note feedback section):

[image]

As you can see there is feedback cell, and when I tap on smileys I want it to expand. I change the state and reload the row. This is what happens:

[image]

As you can see, the section completely scrolled off the screen and it is not visible.

If you scroll down, it is fine right there:

[image]

Here is the code that I use:

Method that triggers cell expansion:

```
self.feedbackCellStatus = FeedbackCellStatusExpanded;

NSIndexPath *indexPathToUpdate = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:[self indexOfSection:ReportSectionFeedback]];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathToUpdate] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Here is my height for row:

```
if (indexPath.section == [self indexOfSection:ReportSectionFeedback]) {
        if (self.feedbackCellStatus == FeedbackCellStatusStarting) {
            return FeedbackHeightStarting;
        } else if (self.feedbackCellStatus == FeedbackCellStatusExpanded) {
            return FeedbackHeightExpanded;
        } else if (self.feedbackCellStatus == FeedbackCellStatusDone) {
            return FeedbackHeightDone;
        }
```